# Function's attributes to object without empty ones

Tags: javascript

I have a simple arrow function:

`const db = (url, type, body?) => ({url, type, body})`

and I don't want to return `body` property if it's an empty `db` argument.

Comment: Explain question properly with more details

Comment: just write an if condition

Comment: By "empty", you mean `undefined`? That's exactly what `body` should become when you want to "omit" it - your code already works!

Comment: No, because then there is an entry body: undefined in the resulting object. Furthermore, the question mark after body is not working in a browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask for the value of `body`

```js
const db = (url, type, body) => Object.assign({url, type}, (body ? {body} : {}));
console.log(db("Ele", "Stack"));
console.log(db("Ele", "Stack", "mybody"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
const db = (url, type, body) => (body ? {url, type, body} : {url, type})
```

Comment: OP didin't give details about the body parameter but i guess it's an object. So you must check the length with Object.keys()

Comment: @MaximeGirou An empty object is different from "no object" already, you don't need to count its properties for that.

Comment: It can be anything, it doesn't matter too much. The OP mentioned that if it was not provided, it shouldn't be returned. It it is not provided, body will be undefined and the correct object will be returned. It is true however, that false or an empty body object would return the short object as well

Comment: it depends on what the OP means when he says 'empty'. if it is an empty object or undefined

Answer (score 0):

**You can check this way**

```
const db = (url, type, body) => (Object.keys(body).length > 0 ? { url, type, body } : { url, type })
```

Comment: Nobody said body needed to be an object. If it is not passed to the function, a simple undefined check is enough